# How to send the data in request payload for Jquery JTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

```
   $('#CDRTableContainer').jtable({
        title : 'CDR Search',
     paging: true,
     pageSize: 500,      
     actions: {
         listAction: 'Controller?action=list'
     },

     fields:fields
    });
```

I would like to give a post request having a json object in request payload to get some response rendering in JTable UI. Can you help me how to send a json in payload.